# How to while POSTING data save it to the logged in user? (Asp net core API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a rest API in ASP NET CORE and I pass a JWT Bearer token to authorize.

My token contains a `NameIdentifier` claim that is the current users id.

My `ApplicationUser` has a one-to-many relationship with another class called `Contact`.

When I `POST` a new `Contact`, I would like it to be added to the list of `Contacts`. How would I achieve this neatly? I have done it this way and it works but I don't really know if this is the best way to achieve this.  (Don't worry about that user ID string, it can be empty or null for now.)

**Contact class:**

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Address VisitingAddress { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `POST` method in my `ContactsController`.

If I assign the `ApplicationUserId` to the userId of the logged in user to the `Contact` class, Core EF automatically figures out that it should be added to `ApplicationUser` list of `Contacts`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Contact contact)
{
    var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    contact.ApplicationUserId = userId;
    var result = await _repository.Add(contact);
    if (result == null) return BadRequest();
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = contact.Id }, contact);
}
```

This is my `GET` method.

It gets a full list of `Contacts` at first but I filter them out before returning. Is this a good way to go or is there neater way to do this?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var result = await _repository.GetAll();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
    {
        result = result.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == userId).ToList();
    }

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: That is a good starting point. If this just for some practice then it already neat. But if you are developing with a real app and with a team better to use a architecture design. As a starting point you can start with this [Introduction To Domain Driven Design](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dev4634/introduction-to-domain-driven-design/)

Comment: Thanks! So my approach is right, I might need to be design it a little different but it is right?!

Comment: there is no right or wrong in the implementation. It's just a matter of a preference. Of course in real world scenario we have a preference  which is an architecture design and it depends what the lead will implement in the development of the project. Happy coding. Cheers!